# Java - How to Load a Custom Font From a Resources Folder

Tags: java, swing, fonts, embedded-resource

I'm using java swing to create an app, but I'm also stuck trying to load some font!
Here is the problem:
I Have a resource folder with some custom font, when I try to load them using this code:

```
    public static Font CustomFont(String path) {
        Font customFont = loadFont(path, 24f);
        System.out.println(customFont == null);
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        ge.registerFont(customFont);
        return customFont;

    }
    public static Font loadFont(String path, float size){
        try {
            Font myFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, Launcher.class.getResourceAsStream(path));
            return myFont.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, size);
        } catch (FontFormatException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

**UiFonts.java**

```
    public static Font Nunito;

    public static void init() {
        Nunito = CustomFont("Fonts/Nunito/Nunito-BlackItalic.ttf");
    }
```

This is my resource folder:
[My project file and folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TfpW.png)

It always show me error depending on the path.

Example: Cant read font file data.

## Solution

I needed to add `/` before the `Font` like this:

`Nunito = CustomFont("/Fonts/Nunito/Nunito-BlackItalic.ttf");`

Also my resources folder wasn't in my java folder. Now it look like this:
[Solution project file and code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2nw6.png)

Comment: *"Example: Cant read font file data."* Always copy/paste error and exception output! BTW - it would be more useful if the tree on the left were expanded all the way down to `Nunito-BlackItalic.ttf`. Can you create a new screenshot? The code on the right is irrelevant, so expand the width of the tree as wide as needed.

Comment: Using `Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, Launcher.class.getResourceAsStream(path));` in a `static` method will typically result in the system class loader which is not meant for application resources. Better to create an object  of one of the classes of your app, then call `obj.getClass().getResource(path)`. Also typically simpler and more useful to get an `URL` using `getResource(path)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to have a read on [Accessing Resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html#overview) in Java.

You need leading */* denotes the root of your class path as well as the *resource* package name.

```
Nunito = CustomFont("/resources/Fonts/Nunito/Nunito-BlackItalic.ttf");
```

With that being said I can't tell where you class is, it's weird your *resources* folder/package is separate from your java usually they would be in the same folder just in a different package.

Comment: No i'm still getting java.io.IOException: Problem reading font data.

Comment: Yeah as I said your app structure seems a bit weird... are your fonts embedded in the jar file itself or is it a folder alongside the jar file

Comment: Did this actually solve your problem? If it did not you do not need to mark it as solved. Also my last comment was meant to be a question for further information

Comment: I saw your update. The resources folder should be further nested in packages com -> your package name -> resources. Then you would access it as above in my answer